# Is it possible to declare a method receiving a Type argument which is restricted to a specific interface in C#?

Tags: c#

If I have a method signature

```
public void Foo(Type fooType)
{
   //...
}
```

and an interface `IFoo`, can I define the above method restricting the `Type` received to be deriving from `IFoo`? In short, I wonder if it's possible to prevent the method for being called this way, for example :

```
Foo(typeof(int));
```

Is it possible to restrict `Type` to a specific interface implementation?

### **Note**

To be clear, in Java, I would have declared the method like this

```
public void Foo(Class<? extends IFoo> fooType)
```

and would have called it with

```
Foo(SomeFoo.class);
```

Comment: Check `typeof(IFoo).IsAssignableFrom(fooType)`.

Comment: Why the method receives a `Type` and is not generic?

Comment: @TimSchmelter because I  need to access the type, not an instance of the type. And having this be generic is exactly the point of the question; whether or not it is possible.

Comment: You can declare generic version with type constraint that's gonna call non-generic version

Comment: @YanickRochon: Being generic doesn't mean you need an instance of the type. You could have `public void Foo<T>() where T : IFoo`. No instances involved. You say "having this be generic is exactly the point of the question" but your question doesn't actually mention generics other than in the tag, so it's hard to see how that works...

Comment: @JonSkeet ah! right. My Java keeps confusing my C#-foo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really need a `Type` as parameter, make your method private and add

```
public void Foo<T>() where T : IFoo
{
    Foo(typeof(T));
}
```

and call it like

```
Foo<MyType>();
```

Clearly, this requires the type to be known at compile time. If this is not the case, you can only do a runtime check as suggested in the comments:

```
if (!typeof(IFoo).IsAssingableFrom(fooType)) throw AnySuitableException();
```

Comment: That wouldn't prevent the code the OP asked to not be possible from being possible though.  You would still be able to pass types not implementing the interface to `Foo`, even if this overload wouldn't.

Comment: @Servy as I wrote: "make your method private"

Comment: Then they can't call it with a `Type`, which is *precisely the requirements of the question*.  Sure, if you just *change the problem into one different than what was asked* you can solve it.

Comment: @Servy: If you want compile time safety use generics, if you want runtime safety pass a type and throw an exception if it doesn't match the requirement. You can't have both at the same time and the answer mentioned it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, that's precisely what my answer says.  I'm glad  you're in agreement.

Comment: @TimSchmelter This answer *doesn't* mention that.  It just says, "use generics instead", that solves your problem, despite the fact that *it doesn't solve the problem asked*.  It solves a different problem not asked by this question.

Comment: The only example the OP gave used a type known at compile time. Whether or not there is a requirement that the type might be determined at runtime only is not 100% clear.

Comment: @KlausGütter The requirement of the question is accepting a `Type`.  **That is the requirement of the question**.   It was not ambiguous.  If you didn't believe them anyway, they said in the comments that they consider generics unacceptable as the type isn't known at compile time.  That they did as SO requires and provide a minimal reproducible example in their one example of calling it doesn't mean that's the only way they will ever call it or invalidate what the question actually asks, indicating the method must accept a `Type`.

Comment: @KlausGütter I have edited the question to provide a Java equivalent of what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.  The whole point of `Type` is that it allows you to utilize types *not known at compile time*.  You can't place compile time level restrictions on types that are, by design, unknown at compile time.

The only way to place *compile time* restrictions on a type is for that type *to be known at compile time*, which is what generics represent.  If in your actual application you *do* know the type at compile time, and don't need to use a `Type`, then you can use generics.  If you really are in the situation described in the question where you only have a `Type`, you can only change the runtime behavior of the method, not whether or not it can be called.

Comment: It seems to be possible in Java, if I recall (I haven't touched Java in years), with declarations like `Class<? extends IFoo> type`

Comment: @YanickRochon Generics can have constraints, yes.  That's because generics know what the type is *at compile time*.  if you're dealing with `Type` instances instead of generics, then, as mentioned, *you do not know what the type is at compile time*, that's the whole point of using `Type`.

Comment: The problem with the suggested answer, however, is that I can't rely on an abstract implementation; I can't dynamically call this with a dynamic type, like I would in Java.

Comment: @YanickRochon You can, you just don't have compile time verification that it will be valid, which should be an obvious consequence given the requirement that the type not be known at compile time.

Comment: @YanickRochon: it's still not clear if the type is known at compile time. Your example `Foo(typeof(int));` suggests that it's known at compile time, then use generics and if you really need the type use [Klaus approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68212209/284240). Otherwise it's not possible and you must check the type at runtime and throw if an invalid type is passed. I assume that you aren't familiar with generics in C#.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Given that they've mentioned generics several times and said they can't use it, why are you assuming they aren't familiar with generics?  And why would you say it's not clear if the type is known at compile time in response to a comment in which they specifically ask about calling it with a dynamic type?

Comment: @Servy: Who is _they_? I assume it because he seems to avoid Klaus generic approach for unknown reasons but the provided examples in C# and Java suggest that the type is known at compile time: `Foo(typeof(int))` and `Foo(SomeFoo.class);`

Comment: @TimSchmelter "they" is the OP.  Given that they've explicitly stated that they can't use generics and have a dynamic type, I wouldn't say there's "unknown reasons" they're avoiding the approach that doesn't answer the question or solve the problem asked about.  Again, that they provided one example, for the sake of an MVCE, in which the type is known at compile time *despite stating in the question that they need a `Type` doesn't indicate that they will always know the type at compile time.

Comment: @Servy: OP is singular for me, however. Where has the OP stated that he can't use generics? Quote: "having this be generic is exactly the point of the question; whether or not it is possible". He stated that he needs to access the type, well, i doubt that he needs it, but it's possible with Klaus approach. I have upvoted your answer because you're explaining exactly the problem. But i'm not convinced that OP can't solve it with a different approach.

Comment: @TimSchmelter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68212084/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-method-receiving-a-type-argument-which-is-restricted/68212254?noredirect=1#comment120556247_68212084 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68212084/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-method-receiving-a-type-argument-which-is-restricted/68212254?noredirect=1#comment120556665_68212254

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234421/discussion-between-tim-schmelter-and-servy).